# An identity involving derivative with respect to Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, trace

I was reading a paper and I encountered an expression that I think is wrong, but I am not completely sure. The expression is: $$\mbox{tr}\left[\dfrac{\partial[|\mbox{tr}(AB)|^2]}{\partial B} C\right] = \dfrac{\partial[\mbox{tr}(AB)\mbox{tr}(AB)^\ast]}{\partial B_{ji}}C_{ji} = A_{ij}\mbox{tr}(AB)^\ast C_{ji} = \mbox{tr}(AC)\mbox{tr}(AB)^\ast$$

My problem is in the very first passage (if that is correct, than the rest is also correct. The paper uses the Einstein convention for summations and use the Wirtinger calculus for the derivatives.

My problem with the first passage is that I think it should be $B_{ij}$ instead of $B_{ji}$ but I am afraid I must be confused with the notation.

Can somebody please take a look and tell me if this is in fact wrong or the notation is tricking me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends on the [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) the author is using.

Comment: @user10354138 he is using the numerator layout

Comment: I haven't thought too much about this, but here's a comment: Instead of multiplying by the *complex conjugate* of the trace, they multiplied by the trace of the *hermitian conjugate*, which means the complex conjugate of the *transpose*. So I think the author is trying to transpose the resulting derivative matrix. Do we know anything about $A$?

Comment: The final result is missing a transpose. It should be $${\rm tr}(A^TC)\;{\rm tr}(AB)^*$$ The result preceeding it (in index notation) is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the author is using the numerator layout,
$$
\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\mathbf{X}}\right)_{ij}=\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial X_{ji}}\right)
$$
So
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left[\frac{\partial[\lvert\operatorname{tr}(AB)\rvert^2]}{\partial B}C\right]=
\left(\frac{\partial[\lvert\operatorname{tr}(AB)\rvert^2]}{\partial B}\right)_{ij}C_{ji}=
\left(\frac{\partial[\lvert\operatorname{tr}(AB)\rvert^2]}{\partial B_{ij}}\right)C_{ji}
$$
is correct.